# How to allow users to mount windows shares

Tags: mount, windows, samba

Our company uses both Windows and Linux. Each user has access to many Windows Shares, e.g. `\\machine1\A`, `\\machine2\B`, etc.

In Ubuntu, how to allow non-root users accessing those shares?

Is there a way to access those without mounting?

If mounting is required, how to allow non-root users to mount network shares to their home folders? They should be able to mount `\\machine1\A` to `/home/user/somefolder/` but cannot change the mounting of local drives.

Comment: Usually you install Samba on the client machine. Then, the user selects "connect to server" and uses the uri `smb://<server_name>`. Also see questions like [How to connect to smb://…?](https://askubuntu.com/q/486450) and [How do I connect to an SMB share requiring a user name and password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/203585)

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is done by adding the setting `user` to the `/etc/fstab` entry which defines the mount points.

Further reading:

- [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)

  > Normally, only the superuser can mount filesystems.  However,
  >   when `fstab` contains the `user` option on a line, anybody can
  >   mount the corresponding filesystem.
- [fstab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)

  The fourth field (fs_mntops).
            This field describes the mount options associated with the
            filesystem.

  ```
        It is formatted as a comma-separated list of options.  It
        contains at least the type of mount (ro or rw), plus any
        additional options appropriate to the filesystem type
        (including performance-tuning options).  For details, see
        mount(8) or swapon(8).

        Basic filesystem-independent options are:

        defaults
               use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser,
               and async.

        noauto do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at boot
               time)

        user   allow a user to mount
  ```

Comment: How do I know which file systems to put into fstab? The number of network paths are unbounded. A user may want to access files from his machine, for example.